# Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) concurrent access: worst scenario

Tags: c#, concurrency

So I have `Dictionary<string, SomeClass>` which will be accessed heavily by multiple concurrent threads - some will write, most will read. No locks, no synchronization - worker thread will make no checks - simply read or write. The only guarantee is that no two threads will write value with same key. The question is could this data structure become corrupted this way? By corrupted I mean not working anymore even with one thread.

Comment: What do you mean by *not working anymore*?

Comment: @Yuck Well, throwing some weird exceptions while performing normal operations or something like that. Msdn only says "not thread-safe" without going into detail. Does it mean a possibility for corruption or just non-atomicity of operations?

Comment: "not thread-safe" doesn't need more detail, and it would be usually very hard to list all possible errors. And the really nasty ones only occur once a year or so. Nice when you have to find/repro them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The worst-case scenarios include:

- **NullReferenceException or IndexOutOfRangeException** thrown out of a Dictionary<,> method.
- **An arbitrary amount of data is lost**. If two threads attempt to resize the Dictionary<,> table at the same time, they can stomp on each other, screw up, and lose data.
- **Wrong answer is returned** by a read from the Dictionary<,>.

Basically, the Dictionary<,> can do just about anything bad you can think of, within the limits imposed by the CLR. Presumably, you still won't break type safety or corrupt the heap as you could in a native programming language. Probably, anyways :-)

Answer (score 8):

> could this data structure become corrupted this way?

Yes, most likely you would get an IndexOutOfRange or similar exception.
And even when you catch and ignore the exceptions, you would not get reliable data any more. Both duplicates and missing values are possible.

So just don't do this.

Comment: +1.  Specifically, from the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx): "A Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization."

Answer (score 2):

If you're accessing a collection from multiple threads, it would be safest to use one of the threadsafe varieties in .Net 4, such as [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)